# Android Custom calling screen issue

Tags: android

I have customize the calling screen using the PhoneStateListener

```
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                // called when someone is ringing to this phone
                AppLog.e(TAG,"Ringing");

                i1 = new Intent(ctx, IncomingScreenActivity.class);

                if(mcurrentTheme.equals("")||mcurrentTheme.equals("default")){
                    AppLog.e(TAG, "Either Default Theme or SharedPreference is not Available");
                } else {

                    ActivityManager localActivityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService("activity");
                    for (String str = ((ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo) localActivityManager
                            .getRunningTasks(1).get(0)).topActivity
                            .flattenToString();; str = ((ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo) localActivityManager
                            .getRunningTasks(1).get(0)).topActivity
                            .flattenToString()) {
                        if ((!str.contains("com.android.phone.InCallScreen")))
                            continue;
                        AppLog.d("IncomingCallPlus",
                                "*****************************************************");
                        i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        i1.putExtra("incoming", incomingNumber);
                        i1.setAction("com.cygnet.ThemeApp.action");
                        ctx.startActivity(i1);

                        return;
                }
```

So when state is Rining mode I fire the intent to open my calling activity
But when phone is on lock and someone call on phone then it show me lock screen then my calling activity

Anyone have any idea how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have searched in Android source code

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.1_r1/com/android/phone/InCallScreen.java?av=f

Add `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` on activity start.

Comment: Link's not valid anymore. Please consider updating it.